# Ace2 Code editor php inline highlighting doesnt work anymore

Tags: ace-editor

I don't know why, but in the latest version of ace2 editor the code highlighting doesn't work anymore.

Here is my code:

```
 this.coding = ace.edit(this.editor[0]);
 this.coding.session.setMode({path:"ace/mode/php", inline:true});
```

Here is the result

[image]

It only highlights very very little, function and strings are not e.g. .

Anymore ever expericened this issue as well?

Comment: What is ace2? The issue doesn't seem to happen with the official ace release from npm ace-builds.

Comment: Ace 2 ist a code editor, see: https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace

Comment: but that is ace, and it doesn't have version 2